# DataInputStream.skip equivalent in C#

Tags: c#

I am reading values from a byte array in a switch case, if none of the switch case matches, in the default I need to skip some number of bytes. In java it is achieved by using the DataInputStream class method skip(numberOfbytes). how can we do the same in c#?

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use [`Stream.Seek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek.aspx) or (my personal preference) use the [`Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position.aspx) property:

```
stream.Position += bytesToSkip;
```

That assumes you're dealing with a seekable stream of course.

Comment: What is the difference between the two? Why do you prefer position to seek?

Comment: @Prescott: I don't believe there *is* any difference to be honest - Seek is the more traditional interface (similar to the C API) but I find Position easier to understand and get right.